# Is there other native metrics/analytics plugin for Adobe Flash?

Tags: flash, google-analytics, adobe-analytics

I  know there is a Google analytics plugin for flash and obviously Omniture integration with flash.

Anyone else know other native AS3 integration of metric/analytics services?

I've searched around but seams that there are not so many offering around the web.

Comment: worst case scenario is you can create a javascript wrapper function to pop  something for xyz tracking tool, and then just make the external js call within flash at relevant times. So I think maybe you are looking at this from the wrong direction.. find an analytics tool that you like (as far as reports, interface features, etc.) and then look into what it takes to implement it code-wise.

Comment: Also, it might help if you provide some backstory.. any reason why you can't/won't use GA or AA?

Comment: My client surpass easily the limit of free GA, their product is totally based on flash, they have many clients, some of them are smaller and use GA others use Omniture, being future proof I don't like to suggest an all in one solution with adobe's technology.